# How to find objects with a join in common?

Tags: django

How do I find all the Members that bob shares a group with?

```
class Member(Model):
     name = CharField(max_length=30)

class GroupMember(Model):
     member = ForeignKey(Member)
     group  = ForeignKey(Group)

class Group(Model):
     name = CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: There is no such field -- `ForeignKeyField`

Comment: Sorry. Meant "ForeignKey". Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Member.objects.filter(group__in=bob.group_set.all()).exclude(pk=bob.pk)
```

**Edit** I didn't notice that you didn't have a ManyToMany relationship set up between Member and Group. You'll need to add that:

```
class Group(Model):
   name = CharField(max_length=30)
   members = ManyToManyField(Member, through='Membership')
```

now syncdb and it should work.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'group_set'